# Selecting a item of a table? with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I'm tryng to select a item ( the first phone, whatever it is) in the o2 web page.
I'm in https://www.o2.co.uk/shop, I select the paymonthly tab, but I'm not able to select the first phone in the list, I'm trying doing:

```
        List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.className("tab-contents"));
    String[] linksText = new String[linkElements.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for(WebElement element : linkElements){

        linksText[index++] = element.getText();
        if(index==1){
            element.click();
        }
    }
```

But it's not running. 
Anyone can help me ? I'm learning how to use selenium, therefore, I dont have many experience in it. Sorry if that is so easy to ask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector returns the container for all the phones. To get the link container for each phone:

```
List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tab-contents a"));
```

Comment: Hi , many thanks for your suggestion. My way to select the phones was not wrong, but it thinks we are selecting empty element or hidden. 
I've added "if(element.isdisplayed())"  and now it's running.

if(element.isDisplayed()){
       element.click();
       break;
      }

Thanks and regards